# Django Rest Framework won't serialize GeoJSON properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to calculate a polygon based on latitude/longitude of center point, radius, and number of sides in Django Rest Framework to expose an API. I have it mostly working, but the serializer doesn't convert the property model into a geoJSON properly. I have included my code below

Serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from .models import Circle
from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeoFeatureModelSerializer


class CircleSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Circle
        fields = ('lat', 'lng', 'radius', 'resolution', 'id', 'polygon')
        geo_field = 'polygon'
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import CircleSerializer
from .models import Circle
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
class CircleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Circle.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = CircleSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Circle', views.CircleViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

models.py

```
# from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
import math
import decimal


# Create your models here.
class Circle(models.Model):
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8)
    radius = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=8)
    resolution = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(3)])
    id = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    polygon = models.PolygonField(null=True, default=None)

    @property
    def polygon(self):
        coords = []
        angle = decimal.Decimal(2 * math.pi / self.resolution)
        for point in range(self.resolution):
            coords.append((self.lng + self.radius * decimal.Decimal(math.sin(point * angle)),
                          self.lat + self.radius * decimal.Decimal(math.cos(point * angle))
                          ))
        return coords

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Output.js

```
    {
    "id": "8",
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": [
        [
            -116.9734681,
            132.801155
        ],
        [
            -86.07176866250526,
            127.90680662951536
        ],
        [
            -58.19494287075268,
            113.70285443749475
        ],
        [
            -36.071768662505264,
            91.57968022924733
        ],
        [
            -21.867816470484648,
            63.70285443749474
        ],
        [
            -16.9734681,
            32.80115500000001
        ],
        [
            -21.867816470484637,
            1.899455562505266
        ],
        [
            -36.07176866250526,
            -25.977370229247303
        ],
        [
            -58.194942870752676,
            -48.10054443749473
        ],
        [
            -86.07176866250525,
            -62.304496629515356
        ],
        [
            -116.97346809999999,
            -67.198845
        ],
        [
            -147.87516753749472,
            -62.30449662951536
        ],
        [
            -175.7519933292473,
            -48.10054443749475
        ],
        [
            -197.87516753749475,
            -25.977370229247324
        ],
        [
            -212.07911972951536,
            1.8994555625052438
        ],
        [
            -216.9734681,
            32.80115499999998
        ],
        [
            -212.07911972951536,
            63.70285443749472
        ],
        [
            -197.87516753749475,
            91.57968022924729
        ],
        [
            -175.7519933292473,
            113.70285443749474
        ],
        [
            -147.87516753749478,
            127.90680662951536
        ]
    ],
    "properties": {
        "lat": "32.80115500",
        "lng": "-116.97346810",
        "radius": "100.00000000",
        "resolution": 20
    }
}
```

Expected Output.js (With the same coordinates above. The below is just an example geoJSON)

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -115.31249999999999,
              32.54681317351514
            ],
            [
              -113.90625,
              34.016241889667015
            ],
            [
              -116.3671875,
              36.31512514748051
            ],
            [
              -116.71874999999999,
              33.43144133557529
            ],
            [
              -115.31249999999999,
              32.54681317351514
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share what output you are getting, and what you expect?

Comment: I updated my response to include the output as well as an example geoJSON to show what I expect. Thank you for your help.